# Need help converting a rxjs forkjoin call to an async call (inside an ngrx @Effect)

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular2-services, ngrx

I want to refactor a set of service calls that i have working using forkJoin.  I have an array of items that comes from the ngrx Store<> and I need to make an http call for each item).

The problem w/forkjoin is that it is essentially a blocking operation, so i need to wait for ALL the calls to finish before it returns - and it could be a long list.

I want to the calls to be async - so to loop on the each item, call the service, and return the result so the UI updates the item.  (To complicate things a bit, this is wrapped inside an ngrx @Effect)

Here is my working code:

```js
@Effect()
    loadItemValues$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .ofType(setActions.LOAD_ITEMS_DATA)
        .map(toPayload)
        .switchMap(key => {
            return this.store.select(fromRoot.getItems)
                .flatMap(items => {
                    let observables = new Array();
                    for (let i of items) {
                        observables.push(this.myService.getItemInfo(i, key));
                    }
                    return Observable.forkJoin(observables)
                    .map((res: Grades[]) => {
                        return new setActions.LoadValuesSuccessAction(res); 
                    })
                })
        })
```

I have assumed that I need to create a new Observable and use flatmap again, but figuring out how/what to pass back up the chain to ensure the service gets called for each item and subsequently calls the LoadValuesSuccessAction Reducer w/the result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want the values emitted one-by-one, each in a `LoadValuesSuccessAction` - with each action containing an array with a single value in it?

Comment: @cartant that is correct.  The Success Action sets the state (via the reducer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change is minor. All you should need to do is replace this:

```ts
return Observable.forkJoin(observables)
.map((res: Grades[]) => {
    return new setActions.LoadValuesSuccessAction(res); 
})
```

with this:

```ts
return Observable.merge(...observables)
.map((res: Grades) => {
    return new setActions.LoadValuesSuccessAction([res]);
})
```

Instead of using `forkJoin`, just use `merge`. That will seen the individual `Grades` emitted (as soon as they are available) instead of a single `Grades[]`. You will also need to wrap the received `res` in an array, as it seems likely your action creator accepts a `Grades[]` argument.

Comment: Thanks cartant - looks like that is working.  Quick question, what does the ellipses do?

Comment: It's the [array spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_array_literals). Many RxJS methods accept multiple observable parameters and they behave consistently when multiples are passed. Some, however, behave differently when passed an array (e.g. `forkJoin` treats an array parameter the same as multiple observable parameters, but `concat` does not - it treats an array as an [`ObservableInput`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObservableInputDoc.html)) so I favour using the spread syntax for consistency.